# Program hangs indefinitely after two threads print even off numbers alternatively

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying inter-thread communication. In below program I am trying to make two threads print even and dd numbers alternatively. They print numbers properly but program never exits. I think both threads are waiting on lock, in a deadlock. Please help me in understanding how to tackle this situation

```
package Test;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ConcurrencyTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadM("odd",lock));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadM("even",lock));
        t1.setName("Odd thread");
        t2.setName("Even thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class ThreadM implements Runnable{
    int start;
    int max;
    Object lock;
    String startAt;
    public ThreadM(String startAt, Object lock) {
        this.start = 1;
        this.startAt = startAt;
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            if("even".equals(startAt)) {
                printEven();
            } else {
                printOdd();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ThreadM.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void printEven() throws InterruptedException {
        while(this.start <= 100) {
            if(this.start % 2 == 0) {
                synchronized(lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Printing even >> "+this.start);
                lock.notify();
                lock.wait();
                }
            }
            this.start++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" >> "+this.start);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
        while(this.start <= 100) {
            if(this.start % 2 == 1) {
                synchronized(lock) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Printing odd >> "+this.start);               
                    lock.notify();
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
            this.start++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" >> "+this.start);
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's a sample output. Numbers go till 100 so, I am pasting last few lines of output

```
Even threadPrinting even >> 96
Odd threadPrinting odd >> 97
Even threadPrinting even >> 98
Odd threadPrinting odd >> 99
Even threadPrinting even >> 100
```

Threads print exactly till 100 then hang up

Comment: You should look at thread dump to get clues on where your threads are stuck.

Comment: After printing you always wait, so it is going to hang on the last result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having printed out `100`, the even thread then enters `lock.wait();`. There is nothing to take it out of that wait (the other thread has either already terminated, or will terminate imminently), so it sits there forever.

Comment: this.start is local not used outside each thread so why should it be made atomic or declared volatile? The only shared object I see is lock.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by NPE, even thread is waiting. You should simply add a `lock.notify()` before exiting form odd thread :

```
private void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
    while(this.start <= 100) {
        if(this.start % 2 == 1) {
            synchronized(lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Printing odd >> "+this.start);               
                lock.notify();
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        this.start++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" >> "+this.start);
    }
    synchronized(lock) {
            lock.notify();
    }
}
```

Here is the end of output with this slight change :

```
Odd thread Printing odd >> 99
Even thread >> 99
Even thread >> 100
Even threadPrinting even >> 100
Odd thread >> 100
Odd thread >> 101
Even thread >> 101
done
```